# Making a method that paints on an applet when actionListener is activated

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, graphics, applet

Problem: I am trying to add multiple methods that use Java's built-in graphics method. The method that paints to the screen uses a if-statement.

What I've Tried: Playing around with the method name and changing the character in (Graphics g). Also I have tried to put the method I'm having problems with into the paint method block.

Variables used:

- wordLengths = an array that stores the amount of words with a certain length. E.g. wordLengths[0] will be 1 if I have 1, 1 letter word.

The following code prints my initials, blanks out the text field and paints the x and y axis of a chart:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("BWD", 450, 490);    // Puts my signature in the bottom corner
        inputField.setText("");
        inputText = ("");
        g.drawLine(50, 450, 460, 450);//Paints  x-axis
        g.drawLine(50, 450, 50, 100);//Paints the y-axis
    }
```

The following code have the method name paint. I have tried to change this, but it still returns issues. When the submit button is clicked, I want the following code to paint to the screen:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
        for(int j=0, x=50, y = 100; j< wordLengths.length;j++)
        {
            if (wordLengths[j] == 1)
            {
                y = y+15;
                g.drawString(wordLengths[j]+ " word of length "+ (j+1), x, y);                              
            }

            g.drawString("There are: ", 50, 90);

            if (wordLengths[j] > 1)
            {
                y = y+15;
                g.drawString(wordLengths[j]+ " words of length "+ (j+1), x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

The ideal code would be this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("BWD", 450, 490);    // Puts my signature in the bottom corner
            inputField.setText("");
            inputText = ("");
            g.drawLine(50, 450, 460, 450);//Paints  x-axis
            g.drawLine(50, 450, 50, 100);//Paints the y-axis

           for(int j=0, x=50, y = 100; j< wordLengths.length;j++)
            {
                if (wordLengths[j] == 1)
                {
                    y = y+15;
                    g.drawString(wordLengths[j]+ " word of length "+ (j+1), x, y);                              
                }

                g.drawString("There are: ", 50, 90);

                if (wordLengths[j] > 1)
                {
                    y = y+15;
                    g.drawString(wordLengths[j]+ " words of length "+ (j+1), x, y);
                }
            }

        }
```

If any other information is required, please do not hesitate to add a comment and I will include it extremely quickly!

Thanks in advance!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java_assignment.JavaAppletMain.paint(JavaAppletMain.java:114)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
at sun.lwawt.LWRepaintArea.paintComponent(LWRepaintArea.java:54)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleJavaPaintEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1267)
at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1150)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4937)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91))

    Thread [AWT-EventQueue-1] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 112 in JavaAppletMain))    
    JavaAppletMain.paint(Graphics) line: 112    
    LWRepaintArea(RepaintArea).paintComponent(Component, Graphics) line: 264    
    LWRepaintArea.paintComponent(Component, Graphics) line: 54  
    LWRepaintArea(RepaintArea).paint(Object, boolean) line: 240 
    LWPanelPeer(LWComponentPeer<T,D>).handleJavaPaintEvent() line: 1267 
    LWPanelPeer(LWComponentPeer<T,D>).handleEvent(AWTEvent) line: 1150  
    JavaAppletMain(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 4937    
    JavaAppletMain(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2287    
    JavaAppletMain(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4687    
    EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object) line: 735    
    EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object) line: 103   
    EventQueue$3.run() line: 694    
    EventQueue$3.run() line: 692    
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext) line: 76    
    ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: 87  
    EventQueue$4.run() line: 708    
    EventQueue$4.run() line: 706    
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext) line: 76    
    EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 705    
    EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) line: 242   
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line: 161    
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component) line: 150   
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional) line: 146  
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional) line: 138   
    EventDispatchThread.run() line: 91
```

Comment: Exactly what is the issue? Your `paint()` method starts or not?

Comment: when I include the if-statements into the first block of code I've posted, it returns fatal errors.

Comment: Then paste the stacktrace(Errors) here.

Comment: Put the errors in the post. Thank you

Comment: At which line `NullPointerException` is pointing to? Are you sure that the error is at `paint()` method?

Comment: It only returns the error when the for-loop and if-statement is in the paint() method. I assume this is what the error is referring to.

Comment: @AJ. `Thread [AWT-EventQueue-1] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 112 in JavaAppletMain))` refers to  g.drawLine(50, 450, 50, 100);//Paints the y-axis

Comment: Where do you initialize `wordLengths`? I think that's the problem. `wordLenghts` is probably `null` (not yet initialized) when `paint` is called. See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194381/printing-g-drawstring-on-a-new-line-when-for-loop-is-run/22197021#22197021) also. Seems like same homework assignment. You might get some tips.

Comment: @peeskillet its done in the actionPerformed class: `if (e.getSource() == analyseButton) {
            inputText = inputField.getText();
            lengthCountArray = buildLengthsAndCounts(inputText);`

Comment: Yeah that's your problem. `paint` is called when you first start the program, meaning `actionPerformed` is never called yet to initialize the array. You need to initialize it in the constructor, or your `init` method, since it's an applet.

Comment: @peeskillet Thats the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to calls super.paint, otherwise you end up with weird paint artefacts. Font change the state of the component or child components from within the paint method, this set up an infinite loop which will consume your CPU. Use JPanel instead and override its paintComponent method instead, it's double buffered, and won't flicker between updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only initializing your array `wordLenghts` in the `actionPerformed`. But `paint` is called at startup of the program, and `actionPerformed` is never called yet to initialize the array. That't why you're getting the `NPE`.

You should just initialize it in the constructor or `init` method.

```
private int[] wordLength;

@Overrde
public void init() {
    wordLength = new int[0];
}
```

Comment: Paint can be called at anytime, for any number of reasons. That's why the OP shouldn't be changing the state of their components from within the paint method ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer good catch. bradlyduncan if you're reading, note the above comment. `inputField.setText("");` in your `paint` method should _never_ be done.

Comment: I've moved the inputField.setText to my actionPerformed method when submit is clicked and added repaint();. Thank you so much @peeskillet and MadProgrammer !